# How to fix 'DMatrix/Booster has not been intialized or has already been disposed ' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

I trained an xgboost model and saved it. And then I copied it to my another system to predict results through the following codes.

Python 3.7, 
xgboost 0.8, 
conda

The same model file can work if I load the data from a csv file.

```py
try:
    d_input = xgb.DMatrix([].append(input_vector))
    xgb_model = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})
    xgb_model.load_model('./models/xgboost.model')
    print("Load model successfully.")
    print(xgb_model)
    docs[i].weight = xgb_model.predict(d_input)
except Exception as fail_xgb:
    print(fail_xgb)
```

The error messages are:

```
Load model successfully.

<xgboost.core.Booster object at 0x1a1e72d4a8>
b'[11:51:46] src/c_api/c_api.cc:817: DMatrix/Booster has not been intialized or has already been disposed.\n\nStack trace returned 5 entries:\n[bt] (0) 0   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000001a1dfe7181 dmlc::StackTrace() + 305\n[bt] (1) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000001a1dfe6f0f dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 47\n[bt] (2) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x0000001a1e0007c3 XGDMatrixNumCol + 99\n[bt] (3) 3   libffi.6.dylib                      0x000000010b6e6884 ffi_call_unix64 + 76\n[bt] (4) 4   ???                                 0x0000700000e63d70 0x0 + 123145317399920\n\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed. Only need to change

```
d_input = xgb.DMatrix([].append(input_vector))
```

to

```
d_input = xgb.DMatrix([[].append(input_vector)])
```

The exception message was very strange. I was confused by it.